# Does anyone know any specific example of such point set

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Does anyone know any specific or explicit example of a set of $256$
points so that no $10$ are the vertices of a convex $10$-gon?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that Erdos and Szekeres claimed an inductive construction for an example, but it is based on $g_{k,1}(1)=g_{1,l}=0$ and $g_{k,l}$ linearly depends on $g_{k,1}(1)$ and $g_{1,l}(1)$, which means all $g_{k,l}$'s are $0$. But then how would that become a valid example? Anyone knows? Thanks.

Comment: If the one who edited the question is the same as the OP, he should flag for moderator attention to request merging his two accounts.